# Wordpress Page Name and Exist Folder Conflict

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory, permalinks

I'm just want to asked about permalink issue in my wordpress site.

Example, my site "stack.com" folder is like this :
test,
wp-admin,
wp-content, and
wp-includes

And in wordpress I have a page name Test, so wordpress permalink, will turn it to be like this "http://stack.com/test/"

And it'll conflict with my exist folder.

Can anyone tell me how to solved this situation? I can just change the page url, one by one from the wp-admin, but I have more than 40 pages that need to be changed.

Regards,

Ricky

Answer (score 2):

You will find this condition in your main WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment it out so that rewrite rules start invoking WP's `index.php` for real folders as well.